# Xamarin, MVVMCross show DisplayMemberPath instead

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am building a native android project with Xamarin and MVVMCross. I am using a `Mvx.MvxSpinner` as element to load my data in (This is the MVVMCross way).

I have the following problem: I have an class with different data elements and a spinner where I bind a `new List<DataClass>()` with elements in it. **Is there a way to actually bind to the Name property in the dataclass (same as `DisplayMemberPath` in WPF)**

Dataclass:

```
public class DataClass
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<DataClass> Lines
{
    get => GetPropertyValue<ObservableCollection<DataClass>>();
    set => SetPropertyValue(value);
}
```

View:

```
<Mvx.MvxSpinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Lines; SelectedItem SelectedLine" />
```

Comment: I could also just use an adapter if this is not possible.

Comment: What happens if you change `SelectedLine` to `SelectedLine.Name` in your XML binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Default Approach**

By default MvvmCross will just call the `ToString` of your listed model. So you could just override the `ToString` to return the name.

```
public class DataClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

**Template Approach**

If you want more control over the look and feel as well as the binding you can create a custom Xml template.

```
<Mvx.MvxSpinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Lines; SelectedItem SelectedLine"
    local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/item_template_dropdown"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_template_spinner" />
```

`MvxItemTemplate` is the template use when the control is in a at rest state (default). While `MvxDropDownItemTemplate` is the template use when the spinner is in the selecting state.

Item template example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Project.Ui.Droid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
</FrameLayout>
```